# How is scala.Array a Seq?

Tags: scala

I'm a strong Java developer who has very recently started trying to pick up Scala in my free time.  I'm going through the [Scala by Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) PDF from scala-lang.org and am confused how the Quick Sort in the very first example works.  Here is the code:

```
object QuickSort extends App {

  def sort(input: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    if(input.length <= 1) input
    else
    {
      val pivot = input(input.length / 2)
      Array.concat(
          sort(input filter (pivot >)),
               input filter (pivot ==),
          sort(input filter (pivot <))
      )
    }
  }

  sort(Array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)) foreach println
}
```

My question is not with the syntax or anything, but I am confused with where the filter function comes from.  According to the PDF, it says that it comes from the Seq[T] class, and that all Arrays are instances of Seq[T].  That is all fine and dandy and while reading the PDF I was satisfied and a very happy newbie Scala developer.  But then I dug a little deeper and started looking at the [scaladoc for Array[T]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) and also the source code for Array[T] and I do not see how the Array[T] class extends or inherits the Seq[T] trait at all.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing implicits. There's a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-looks-for-implicits) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala) about [implicits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/context-and-view-bounds-again) on Stack Overflow. On the PDF you are reading, see chapter 15, starting on page 113. On Scaladoc, you'll see the relevant implicits on the object `scala.Predef` -- just look for implicit methods which take an `Array` as input parameter and return something else.

PS: Yikes, it says `Array` is a `Seq`! That might have been the case before Scala 2.8, actually, but since then an `Array` is a Java `Array`, pure and simple.

Answer (score 3):

There's an implicit conversion to WrappedArray in Predefs. See [Scala Arrays vs Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131309/scala-arrays-vs-vectors).