# how to use scala api document?

Tags: scala

I've seen the args.foreach(arg => println(arg)), but when I search the doc http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array . I don't find it there and its companion object doc.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: [scalex](http://scalex.org/?q=Array+foreach) can help in such case.

Comment: This was my first Scala question on this site too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131309/scala-arrays-vs-vectors. The docs really need an option to show all methods available from pre-defined implicits (or maybe, option to *hide* them). scalex doesn't do this either so is not helpful unless you already know there's an implicit to `ArrayOps` (in which case you can just look that up the normal API docs)

Answer (score 6):

`Array` gets operations such as `foreach` from `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps` - so you can lookup [`ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps) in the documentation to see what methods are available on arrays.

[`Predef`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/Predef.scala) contains a number of implicit conversion methods to make these available for arrays.

Unfortunately you can't see in the Scala API documentation for `Array` that these methods are available via the implicits in `Predef`.

Answer (score 1):

As Jesper said, it's not really easy to find documentation on methods acquired via implicit conversions.
The ones defined for Array and the rationale behind them are explained [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_38.html).

One (not particularly handy...) general way of finding out where a particular method comes from (in cases like yours, where it comes from an implicit conversion) is to use the `-print` option of the scala REPL.

If you run `scala -print` you will get:

```
scala> Array(1,2,3,4)
// ..... omitted for brevity
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> res0 foreach (println)
[[syntax trees at end of cleanup]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line2 {
  final object $read extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line2.$read = {
      $read.super.this();
      ()
    }
  };
  @SerialVersionUID(0) final <synthetic> class $read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1 extends
scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1 with Serializable {
    final def apply(x: java.lang.Object): Unit = scala.this.Predef.println(x);
    final <bridge> def apply(v1: java.lang.Object): java.lang.Object = {
      $read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.this.apply(v1);
      scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
    };
    def this(): anonymous class $read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1 = {
      $read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.super.this();
      ()
    }
  };
  final object $read$$iw$$iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    private[this] val res1: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def res1(): Unit = ();
    def this(): object $line2.$read$$iw$$iw = {
      $read$$iw$$iw.super.this();
      $read$$iw$$iw.this.res1 = {
        scala.this.Predef.intArrayOps($line1.$read$$iw$$iw.res0()).foreach({
          {
            (new anonymous class $read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1(): Function1)
          }
        });
        scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
      };
      ()
    }
  };
  final object $read$$iw extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object $line2.$read$$iw = {
      $read$$iw.super.this();
      ()
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of cleanup]]// Scala source: <console>
package $line2 {
  final object $eval extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    @volatile protected var bitmap$0: Int = 0;
    <stable> <accessor> lazy def $result(): Unit = {
      if ($eval.this.bitmap$0.&(1).==(0))
        {
          $eval.this.synchronized({
            if ($eval.this.bitmap$0.&(1).==(0))
              {
                {
                  $eval.this.$print();
                  $line2.$read$$iw$$iw.res1()
                };
                $eval.this.bitmap$0 = $eval.this.bitmap$0.|(1);
                ()
              };
            scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
          });
          ()
        };
      ()
    };
    private[this] val $print: java.lang.String = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def $print(): java.lang.String = $eval.this.$print;
    def this(): object $line2.$eval = {
      $eval.super.this();
      $eval.this.$print = {
        $line2.$read$$iw$$iw;
        ""
      };
      ()
    }
  }
}

1
2
3
4
```

If you look for .foreach inside this code, you will find the relevant line, that tells you the method is actually called on `intArrayOps`:

```
scala.this.Predef.intArrayOps($line1.$read$$iw$$iw.res0()).foreach(
```